# What does the User permission 'Cache Diagnostics' mean?

Tags: permissions, user

On the User record, there is field - 'Cache Diagnostics'.

I have Googled around but haven't found any clear information on what this User permission means / does.

Can someone explain what is the significance of this User permission?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The Cache Diagnostics user permission allows you to see detailed information about the Platform Cache feature.

See the [Platform Cache Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_best_practices.htm):

```
Use the Cache Diagnostics Page (Sparingly)

To determine how much of the cache is used, check the Platform Cache Diagnostics page. To reach the Diagnostics page:

Make sure that Cache Diagnostics is enabled for the user (on the User Detail page).

On the Platform Cache Partition page, click the partition name.

Click the link to the Diagnostics page for the partition.
```